# Read MQTT topic of received message in Camel Route

Tags: apache-camel, mqtt

I am trying to configure an Apache Camel Spring Route. I would like to consume messages from MQTT and print them with their topic. How do I get the topic the message was published to?

I'm using Apache Camel 2.16.1
My camel-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="MqttCamel">
        <route>
            <from uri="mqtt:iot?host=tcp://iot.eclipse.org:1883&amp;subscribeTopicNames=#" />
            <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
            <to uri="stream:out" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

With the MQTT component, the topic is stored in a header called "CamelMQTTSubscribeTopic":

```
from("mqtt:foo?subscribeTopicName=#&host=tcp://127.0.0.1:1883")
   .log("Message read from topic ${in.header.CamelMQTTSubscribeTopic}.");
```

Comment: Is there a way to read the header and print to `stream:out` from XML?

Comment: Somehting like this should do it: <setBody>
  <simple>${in.header.CamelMQTTSubscribeTopic}</simple>
</setBody>
<to uri="stream:out" />

Answer (score 1):

If saying Apache Paho they use CamelMqttTopic header name. And it's possible to use

> ${in.header.CamelMqttTopic}

and

> ${header.CamelMqttTopic}

So this

```
from("paho:#")
                .log("Message read from topic ${in.header.CamelMqttTopic}.")
                .log("Message read from topic ${header.CamelMqttTopic}.")
                .bean(mqttService, "received(${header.CamelMqttTopic}, ${body})")
        ;
```

works.

received method is

```
public void received(String topic, String payload) {
        log.info("topic: {}", topic);
        log.info("payload: {}", payload);
    }
```

And i got to my log:

```
Message read from topic my/topic/name.
Message read from topic my/topic/name.
topic: my/topic/name
payload: payload message
```

See here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/Paho

Tested on Paho 2.25.1

Comment: Yeah good idea to use camel-paho for MQTT as its a much more active maintained project than the old fusesource mqtt client.

Comment: How and where are we setting the custom topic header for the paho consumer route? I'm confused